# Image is overflowing outside the size of FlatList single grid

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am currently working on making a grid using FlatList component of the react-native library. I am trying to insert images inside the grids formed inside the FlatList component, but when I am trying to insert the images, the images do not completely fill the particular grid, ther is always the down part of the image which is not displayed in the grid.[image: This is the flatlist where 4 images are inserted, but the images down portion is not visible and gets hidden.]

Code for the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View , StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';


export const HomeGrid = () => {
    return (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Image
                style={{flex: 1, width: size, height: size }}
                source = {item.value}
              />
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={numColumns} />
      );
}

const data = [
    {id: 'a', value: require('../photos/photo3.jpg')},
    {id: 'b', value: require('../photos/photo2.jpeg')},
    {id: 'c', value: require('../photos/photo4.jpg')},
    {id: 'd', value: require('../photos/photo3.jpg')},
    {id: 'e', value: require('../photos/photo2.jpeg')},
    {id: 'f', value: require('../photos/photo4.jpg')}
  ];

const numColumns = 2;
const size = Dimensions.get('window').width/numColumns;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemContainer: {
      width: size,
      height: size,
    },
    item: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    }
  });
```

What could be the workaround for this?

Comment: could you try set resizeMode = 'contain' for Image

Comment: this is putting the full image inside the tile, but is not completely filling it.
How can i contain and fill the image completely inside the FlatList tile?

Comment: if  the image completely fill the tile, it won't remain aspect ratio

Comment: try all these attributes until you get the expected result https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode

Comment: yup stretch worked for me :)